# If you were to hang a wrinkled shirt, would it ever become unwrinkled over time via gravity?

Tags: gravity

If you were to hang a wrinkled shirt, would it ever become unwrinkled over time via gravity?

Comment: Is this not why you put clothes on a clothes hanger?

Comment: @Charlie Depends. Are the internal forces keeping the shirt wrinkled stronger than the tension induced by gravity? Then it'll never unwrinkle itself.

Comment: Under what humidity conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. Imagine a hanging a spring by one end. It would stretch out a lot more than if it were on a table, due to it's own mass. But, it would quickly settle into an equilibrium position. The same is true for a shirt, which has some elasticity within itself. It would unwrinkle a little bit, but settle into some equilibrium.

If you were near a very dense mass, you might be able to accomplish this with tidal forces, which would be actively stretching out the shirt.